# How to get value of a prepopulated username input field in java script or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get the value of the username field when the browser prepopulates it. The javascript is on a cshtml page.  I have tried getting it in the document.render function, but the value is empty.  I tried this using the below code in the render function.

```
console.log(document.getElementById("Username").value.length);
            if (document.getElementById("Username").value.length > 0)
                setTimeout(function () { CallCheckUsernameAvail($("#Username")); }, 1);
```

I also tried to create a document.load function, but even empty, it throws an error in the jquery files (image below)

```
$(document).load(function () { });
```

[Image of jQuery url indexOf error from dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N923U.png)

Can someone advise how I might access this value when the page first loads?  Thanks!

Comment: Please specify exactly what error you are getting and also supply the relevant actual code (not a picture of code) that you are using including the HTML.

Comment: `$(document).load(...)` to set an onload handler for the document was deprecated and removed some time ago, and you are seeing the code for `$.load` in your debug output, which is the wrong function.  Try `$(document).on('load', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the `ID: Username` belongs to the input field your trying to retrieve the info from you should be able to do something like this

```
$("#Username").val();
```

if its being populated automatically you might need to use a delay or some other crafty method to ensure that the info your trying to get is in the field before your jQuery looks for it, possibly something like this.

```
$("#Username").delay( 800 ).val();
```

Both of these are JQuery solutions